# AWS Application Load Balancer Public Url not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, continuous-deployment, amazon-ecs, aws-application-load-balancer

Below is my configuration:

I have created an ECS cluster with maximum number of task = 1 and with number of ec2.micro instance = 1 and 1 service.
I have configured 1 target group listening to port 80 with Registered targets to the ec2 (belonging to same ECS cluster) and its status is healthy.

I have configured ALB with the above target group with public subnets (both subnets have ig-xxxxxx)
I have configured the service in my ECS cluster with the above Application Load Balancer.
Deployed (to ECS) docker image is binding to host port 80.

When I try to access my app directly from ec2's IP I get 200 with expected json. However the ALB URL is not working whatsoever.

Any idea what am I missing here.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
Ping output:

```
ali@mintvm:~$ ping pl-alb-1386183277.ap-southeast-2.elb.amazonaws.com
PING pl-alb-1386183277.ap-southeast-2.elb.amazonaws.com (54.153.167.227) 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
--- pl-alb-1386183277.ap-southeast-2.elb.amazonaws.com ping statistics ---
13 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 12278ms

ali@mintvm:~$ ping 54.153.167.227
PING 54.153.167.227 (54.153.167.227) 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
--- 54.153.167.227 ping statistics ---
9 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 8197ms

ali@mintvm:~$
```

DIG output:

```
ali@mintvm:~$ dig pl-alb-1386183277.ap-southeast-2.elb.amazonaws.com

; <<>> DiG 9.11.3-1ubuntu1.5-Ubuntu <<>> pl-alb-1386183277.ap-southeast-2.elb.amazonaws.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 26707
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 65494
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;pl-alb-1386183277.ap-southeast-2.elb.amazonaws.com. IN A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
pl-alb-1386183277.ap-southeast-2.elb.amazonaws.com. 60 IN A 54.153.167.227

;; Query time: 207 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.53#53(127.0.0.53)
;; WHEN: Mon May 06 11:51:21 AEST 2019
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 95
```

Screenshot of the VPS settings:

[image]

Route Table has IGW attached to it under "Routes" section.

EDIT 2:
Details of ALB:
[image]

Comment: Have you checked that the ALB's attribute Scheme is internet-facing and not internal?

Comment: What does `dig URL` or `ping URL` return? If these command fails then: Have you enabled DNS support in your VPC? Have you changed the DHCP Option Sets? If the URL resolves, is it returning an IP address that works?

Comment: Hi @JohnHanley when I ping the url runs forever, upon cancelling terminal return the below: my-alb-12232323.ap-southeast-2.elb.amazonaws.com ping statistics ---
258 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 263170ms
I also have the below settings on my vpc:
State = available
Default VPC = No
Classic link = Disabled
DNS resolution = Enabled
DNS hostnames = Enabled
DHCP options set = dopt-8994xxxxx (--> this value is also set at default vpc)
ClassicLink DNS Support = Disabled
Route table = rtb-008124f82xxxxxxxx | ECS plservices - RouteTable (--> route table has igw-xxxx)

Comment: The one piece of information that I wanted you left out. Plus you did not answer my last question. The IP address returned by dig or ping. Edit your question with the output from `dig` and the VPC DNS settings so that everyone will see them. It is just too hard to read details in the comments.

Comment: hi @JohnHanley apology. I have edited the question to add the ping, dig info and VPC settings screenshot. Please let me know if I am missing something. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: If this is an "internal facing" load balancer, it should not have a public IP address. Please double check how you configured your load balancer. You state: "When I try to access my app directly from ec2's IP" - What is the IP address?  I am determining if the IP address is private or public.

Comment: Hi @JohnHanley I can confirm it is NOT an internal facing ALB. See my screenshot of ALB in the comment. EC2's IP meaning ec2 container instances behind the load balancer. I can access the ec2 container instance directly via its publicly available URL to check if my app is running ok. In Go-Live mode only ALB will be internet facing and will assign a pvt subdomain to ec2 containers.